# alternative to zip that produces value whenever any of the observable emit a value

Tags: rxjs

At the moment zip will only produce a value whenever all of the zipped observable produces a value. E.g. from the docs:

> Merges the specified observable sequences or Promises into one
>   observable sequence by using the selector function **whenever all** of the
>   observable sequences have produced an element

I'm looking for an observable which can sort of zip an observable but will produce an array of sequence of the zipped observable wherein it doesn't matter if all produces a value..

e.g. lets say i have tick$, observ1, observ2.. tick$ always produce value every x secs.. while observ1 and observ2 only produces from time to time..
I'm expecting my stream to look like

```
[tick, undefined, observ2Res],
[tick, undefined, undefined],
[tick, observ1Res, observ2Res]
...
...
```

its not combine latest, given that combine latest takes the latest value of a given observable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `buffer` (or maybe `sample`) might get you on the right track. The `buffer` method accepts an Observable that's used to define our buffer boundaries. The resulting stream emits any items that were emitted in that window (example stolen from RXJS docs for `buffer`):

```
var source = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 50)
  .buffer(function () { return Rx.Observable.timer(125); })
  .take(3);

var subscription = source.subscribe(x => console.log('Next: ', x));

// => Next: 0,1,2
// => Next: 3,4,5
// => Next: 6,7
```

So we now have a way to get all of a stream's emitted events in a certain time window. In your case, we can use `tick$` to describe our sampling period and `observ1` and `observ2` are our underlying streams that we want to buffer:

```
const buffered1 = observ1.buffer(tick$);
const buffered2 = observ2.buffer(tick$);
```

Each of these streams will emit once every tick$ period, and will emit a list of all emitted items from the underlying stream (during that period). The `buffered` stream will emit data like this:

```
|--[]--[]--[1, 2, 3]--[]-->
```

To get the output you desire, we can choose to only look at the latest emitted item of each buffered result, and if there's no emitted data, we can pass null:

```
const buffered1 = observ1.buffer($tick).map(latest);
const buffered2 = observ2.buffer($tick).map(latest);

function latest(x) {
    return x.length === 0 ? null : x[x.length - 1];
}
```

The previous sample stream I illustrated will now look like this:

```
|--null--null--3--null-->
```

And finally, we can `zip` these two streams to get "latest" emitted data during our `tick$` interval:

```
const sampled$ = buffered1.zip(buffered2);
```

This `sampled$` stream will emit the latest data from our `observ1` and `observ2` streams over the `tick$` window. Here's a sample result:

```
|--[null, null]--[null, 1]--[1, 2]-->
```

Comment: Calvin, tried this and what I was aiming for. I unfortunately still can upvote but marked this as the answer.